# Cap Chrome's allowed memory on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Hey after a couple of hours browsing in Chrome it's at about 3GB and even closing tabs doesn't change that. Only hitting CMD+Q helps freeing the RAM for me. I only have AdBlock activated and the integrated Chrome Task Manager is knowingly useless.

Any advice here?

Comment: How.many tabs do you have open? What (other) extensions?

Comment: About 30 in total, literally no extensin but AdBlock

Comment: Get more ram installed on your machine

Comment: I highly doubt this will make Chrome release more RAM